# Add class attribute to buttons generated with Perl's CGI::FormBuilder

Tags: css, perl, formbuilder

I am using Perl's `CGI::FormBuilder` class along with `HTML::Template`. To show the submit and reset buttons my template file has these lines:

```
<TMPL_VAR form-submit>
<TMPL_VAR form-reset>
```

Those two template lines generate this HTML code:

```html
<!-- How it looks now. -->
<input id="_submit" name="_submit" type="submit" value="Submit" />
<input id="_reset" name="_reset" type="reset" value="Reset" />
```

I want to add a `class` attribute to the buttons, that is, I want the above HTML to look something like this:

```html
<!-- How I want it to look. -->
<input id="_submit" class="myclass" name="_submit" type="submit" value="Submit" />
<input id="_reset" class="myclass" name="_reset" type="reset" value="Reset" />
```

How would I do this?

Comment: We need a small demonstration of how you end up with that HTML.

Answer (score 1):

The `stylesheet` and `styleclass` arguments to CGI::FormBuilder add class information to the widgets. When you define a field, any key that isn't already taken is assumed to be an HTML attribute:

```
$form->field(
    name  => 'text',
    id    => 'text_input_123',
    class => 'text_class',
    );
```

This is clearly documented for the [field() method](https://metacpan.org/pod/CGI::FormBuilder#field()).

Consider though, that this module is very old (as in `HTML::Template`). Using it for legacy work is one thing, but for new things, generally avoid unsupported modules.

Comment: That works to add the `class` attribute to a specific input element, but how do you add `class` to the buttons generated as I described in my question?